# Swapping object's layers with `front` key in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I avoid the long and very boring codes of my own and focus only on what matter. I produce using the two lines

```
set arrow from xarr_1, yarr_1 to xarr_2, yarr_2 nohead lc 'white' lw 2 front
set object circle at xarr_2, yarr_2 size screen 0.01 fc rgb "black" fillstyle solid 1.0 front
```

the black circle and white zone (which is a pile of arrows) in the following figures (only one is enough)
[image: Image representing two distribution and their mean positions. The white zone is the zone covered by the white during the evolution of our distributions and the black is the current mean position.]
Since on both objects: arrow and circle, I use the key `front` to put them in front of the `plot` command, I would like now the black object to be in front of the arrows "white zone".

How can I do that?

PS: the same issue appears with this simplify code whether you swap the commands

```
reset session 
reset
PI = 4.*atan(1.)
set xrange [-PI:PI]
set arrow from -0.1, 0.1 to 0.1, -0.1 lc 'black' lw 2 front 
set object circle at 0, 0 radius 0.1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fc rgb 'red' front 
plot  sin(x) w l 
pause -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the gnuplot manual (`help layers`) there is a certain order how objects are drawn: arrows in front of labels in front of objects (rectangles, circles, ellipses, polygons). As I understand, you cannot draw a circle in front of an arrow, unless you are using multiplot. If I understood your question correctly, you want to place a circle in front of an arrow. So, you probably have to use multiplot.

Something like this:

```
### plot circle in front of an arrow
reset session

set obj 999 rect from graph 0, graph 0 to graph 1, graph 1 fc rgb "black" behind
set print $Data   # create some random data
do for [i=1:1000] { print sprintf("%g %g", invnorm(rand(0)), invnorm(rand(0)))}
set print

set xrange[-3:3]
set yrange[-3:3]
set multiplot
    set arrow 1 from -1,1 to 1,-1 lc 'white' lw 3
    plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "red"

    set object 1 circle at 0,0 radius 0.5 fillstyle solid 1.0 fc rgb 'blue' front
    unset obj 999 # don't use the black background again
    plot -10 not  # plot some dummy out of range
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

Gives something like this:

[image]